# Sum Sql Columns with common ID Within multiple ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate

This is my SQL

```
SELECT K.SUBTOTAL_PERHOSP - G.SUBTOTAL_PERHOSP AS SOA
    ,K.SUBTOTAL_NOTHOSP - G.SUBTOTAL_NOTHOSP AS Disapproved
    ,G.SUBTOTAL_HB_TOHOSP + H.MEDICARE_INCENTIVES - H.MI_PAYABLES AS HApproved
    ,D.APPROVED
    ,k.fldvat_perhosp
    ,B.CONTROL_CODE
    ,F.OTHER_REMARKS
    ,(G.SUBTOTAL_HB_TOHOSP + H.MEDICARE_INCENTIVES - H.MI_PAYABLES) + (
        SELECT sum(D.APPROVED)
        FROM SYS_IN_PATIENT_MTBL B
        LEFT JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_PROFFEES_MTBL D ON B.CONTROL_CODE = D.CONTROL_CODE
        WHERE B.CONTROL_CODE IN ('IP435168', 'IP435171')
        ) - G.MPI_PERHOSP AS NetPPD
    ,C.GP
    ,B.HOSPITAL_CODE
    ,B.DATE_RCVD
    ,B.DUE_DATE
FROM SYS_IN_PATIENT_MTBL B
INNER JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_COMPUTATION_MTBL K ON B.CONTROL_CODE = K.CONTROL_CODE
INNER JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_DEDUCTION_MTBL G ON B.CONTROL_CODE = G.CONTROL_CODE
LEFT JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_REMARKS_MTBL H ON B.CONTROL_CODE = H.CONTROL_CODE
LEFT JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_PROFFEES_MTBL D ON B.CONTROL_CODE = D.CONTROL_CODE
LEFT JOIN SYS_DOCTOR_LTBL E ON D.PF_CODE = E.DOCTOR_CODE
LEFT JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_INFORMATION_MTBL F ON B.CONTROL_CODE = F.CONTROL_CODE
INNER JOIN SYS_HOSPITALS_LTBL J ON B.HOSPITAL_CODE = J.HOSPITAL_CODE
INNER JOIN SYS_HOSPITALS_LTBL C ON B.HOSPITAL_CODE = C.HOSPITAL_CODE
WHERE B.CONTROL_CODE IN ('IP435168', 'IP435171')
```

and this is the output

[image: Output Wrong]

Notice the Column `NetPPD` it outputs wrong values
it must be 
4,250.70
4,250.70
17,975.21
17,975.21
how can i accomplish this because if i use multiple ID it adds everything in that column and i can't use group by inside a sql that returns one value only
it must be

```
HApproved + Approved(600 + 800) = 4,250.70 (Same Control Code IP435168)
HApproved + Approved(600 + 1300) = 17,975.21 (Same Control Code IP435171)
```

Note: Those Rows will not merge because there is a unique columns in the far right side of table i just not include it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you are adding up all the CONTROL_CODE totals instead of splitting them by code. To solve that move your "Approved Total" sub-query to FROM section and join it on control code. Not sure what the role of hospital code in this is, leaving it out as is not your immediate problem, but you may want to add that to the join. If you share the table definitions, I could do a better job, but below should help:

```
SELECT K.SUBTOTAL_PERHOSP - G.SUBTOTAL_PERHOSP as SOA
    , K.SUBTOTAL_NOTHOSP - G.SUBTOTAL_NOTHOSP as Disapproved
    , G.SUBTOTAL_HB_TOHOSP + H.MEDICARE_INCENTIVES - H.MI_PAYABLES as HApproved
    , D.APPROVED
    , k.fldvat_perhosp
    , B.CONTROL_CODE
    , F.OTHER_REMARKS
    ,(G.SUBTOTAL_HB_TOHOSP + H.MEDICARE_INCENTIVES - H.MI_PAYABLES) + APRV.Approved - G.MPI_PERHOSP as NetPPD
    , C.GP
    , B.HOSPITAL_CODE
    , B.DATE_RCVD
    , B.DUE_DATE
from SYS_IN_PATIENT_MTBL B
    INNER JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_COMPUTATION_MTBL K ON B.CONTROL_CODE = K.CONTROL_CODE
    INNER JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_DEDUCTION_MTBL G ON B.CONTROL_CODE = G.CONTROL_CODE
    LEFT JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_REMARKS_MTBL H ON B.CONTROL_CODE = H.CONTROL_CODE
    LEFT JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_PROFFEES_MTBL D ON B.CONTROL_CODE = D.CONTROL_CODE 
    LEFT JOIN SYS_DOCTOR_LTBL E ON D.PF_CODE = E.DOCTOR_CODE
    LEFT JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_INFORMATION_MTBL F ON B.CONTROL_CODE = F.CONTROL_CODE
    INNER JOIN SYS_HOSPITALS_LTBL J ON B.HOSPITAL_CODE = J.HOSPITAL_CODE
    INNER JOIN SYS_HOSPITALS_LTBL C ON B.HOSPITAL_CODE = C.HOSPITAL_CODE

    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select B.CONTROL_CODE, sum(D.APPROVED) as Approved
                FROM SYS_IN_PATIENT_MTBL B 
                    LEFT JOIN SYS_IP_BILLPROC_PROFFEES_MTBL D ON B.CONTROL_CODE = D.CONTROL_CODE 
                WHERE  B.CONTROL_CODE IN ('IP435168','IP435171')
                GROUP BY B.CONTROL_CODE
            ) AS APRV ON APRV.CONTROL_CODE = B.CONTROL_CODE

where B.CONTROL_CODE IN ('IP435168','IP435171')
```